# Making an array of integers in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

If you want to make an array of integers, can you use NSInteger? Do you have to use NSNumber? If so, then why?

Answer (score 164, accepted):

You can use a plain old C array:

```
NSInteger myIntegers[40];

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 40; i++)
    myIntegers[i] = i;

// to get one of them
NSLog (@"The 4th integer is: %d", myIntegers[3]);
```

Or, you can use an `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray`, but here you will need to wrap up each integer inside an `NSNumber` instance (because `NSArray` objects are designed to hold class instances).

```
NSMutableArray *myIntegers = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 40; i++)
    [myIntegers addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:i]];

// to get one of them
NSLog (@"The 4th integer is: %@", [myIntegers objectAtIndex:3]);

// or
NSLog (@"The 4th integer is: %d", [[myIntegers objectAtIndex:3] integerValue]);
```

Comment: I think it's worth noting that C arrays are such a hassle for anything but trivial, one-off use that it's actually less trouble to wrap any arrays you plan on keeping around as NSArrays of NSNumber.

Comment: Yes, and given the [presumably] expert-level optimisations under the hood of `NSArray`, I'm sure you won't feel the performance hit.

Comment: @dreamlax I wonder what kind of expert-level optimization is under the hood of NSArray? Smart memory allocation that simply probably doubles the size of allocated memory once it hits the limit? :)p

Comment: @Andy: Have a look at the actual source for CFArray [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-476.14/CFArray.c) and check out the benchmarks [here](http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/array.html). It's a little smarter than you would initially think.

Comment: Assuming that this array is just used within a method, there are no issues with using a C array of NSIntegers?Just double checking...

Comment: @DanRosenstark I believe not, since AFAIK `NSInteger` is just `typedef` of `int`.

Answer (score 66):

C array:

```
NSInteger array[6] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
```

Objective-C Array:

```
NSArray *array = @[@1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6];
// numeric values must in that case be wrapped into NSNumbers
```

Swift Array:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

This is correct too:

```
var array = Array(1...10)
```

---

NB: arrays are strongly typed in Swift; in that case, the compiler infers from the content that the array is an array of integers. You could use this explicit-type syntax, too:

```
var array: [Int] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

---

If you wanted an array of Doubles, you would use :

```
var array = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0] // implicit type-inference
```

or:

```
var array: [Double] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] // explicit type
```

Comment: What would be the equivalent "@number" syntax for a negative integer?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use a NSArray, you need an Objective-C class to put in it - hence the NSNumber requirement.

That said, Obj-C is still C, so you can use regular C arrays and hold regular ints instead of NSNumbers if you need to.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [CFArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFArrayRef/Reference/reference.html) instead of NSArray. [Here](http://www.cocoabyss.com/foundation/collections-integers-performance/) is an article explaining how.

```
CFMutableArrayRef ar = CFArrayCreateMutable(NULL, 0, NULL);
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
  CFArrayAppendValue(ar, (void*)i);
}
CFRelease(ar); /* Releasing the array */
```

The same applies for the CoreFoundation version of the other containers too.

Comment: If there's an advantage of using CFArray over NSArray, I don't see it. An NSArray IS a CFArray under the hood; this is just doing it the hard way.

Comment: @Cryptognome there is a small difference here, the CFArray won't retain or release anything because it was created without callbacks. I agree though, there doesn't seem to be any advantage.

Answer (score 4):

I created a simple Objective C wrapper around the good old C array to be used more conveniently: https://gist.github.com/4705733

Answer (score 4):

*If the order of your integers is not required,
 and if there are only unique values*

you can also use NSIndexSet or NSMutableIndexSet
You will be able to easily add and remove integers, or check if your array contains an integer with

```
- (void)addIndex:(NSUInteger)index
- (void)removeIndex:(NSUInteger)index
- (BOOL)containsIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexSet
```

Check the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableIndexSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003693%20NSMutableIndexSet) for more info.

Comment: That's a terrible idea. Here's a piece from Apple's documentation: _You should not use index sets to store an arbitrary collection of integer values because index sets store indexes as sorted ranges. This makes them more efficient than storing a collection of individual integers. It also means that each index value can only appear once in the index set._

Comment: I agree and this is why I started my reply with a warning. However, I know some people who have asking this question about integer arrays, and actually needed an index set. That's why I gave this alternate answer.

Comment: What's wrong with just a regular `NSSet` (and using integers wrapped in an `NSNumber`)?

Comment: @dreamlax overhead, but generally speaking, people asking such questions cannot handle C and they simply have few numbers to store, so NSArray or NSSet must be the best.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a lot easier to use NSNumbers. This all you need to do:

```
NSNumber *myNum1 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:myNsIntValue1];
NSNumber *myNum2 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:myNsIntValue2];
.
.
.
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: myNum1, myNum2, ..., nil];
```

Comment: but what if your array has 10 or 100 numbers?

Comment: You can use `for` or just another array for the numbers, and then `arrayWithArray`.