# define many static integer in a for loop

Tags: objective-c

I need to define many points, about 40. and rather than start writing:

```
static float...
```

for each one of them, i was trying to loop it .but got error.

i did this which i know the % is not in place :

```
  for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
        static CGPoint pixel%i=CGPointMake(px+(i*32), py);


    }
```

when i need to define and assign pixel1 to pixel 40 with values that i can later use.

how should i do that right ?

thanks .

Answer (score 2):

I think you'd be much better off just using an array.

See [Making an array of integers in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340153/making-an-array-of-integers-in-objective-c).

```
CGPoint pixels[20];

for(NSInteger i = 0; i < 20; i++){
  pixels[i] = CGPointMake(px+(i*32), py);
}
```

Comment: thanks but i would rather not use an array. i want names for each point and point. how would i write that to declare them all in one loop ?

Comment: @Rant - I don't believe you can - though someone else here may prove me wrong.  Why *wouldn't* you just use an array?  You've already indicated that you want them consistently named.  It'll also make the rest of your code easier to maintain and work with...